# How to reference the connected mongo db routes in api routes in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

i just started learning mongo db , i connected my database atlas successfully but i need to call the client variable in api routes when i do so it is saying client not connected

```
const express = require("express");
const res = require("express/lib/response");
const app = express()
const {MongoClient} = require("mongodb")


async function main(params) {
let uri = "mongodb+srv://usn:pwd@cluster0.tasg9.mongodb.net/movies?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
const client = new MongoClient(uri)
try{
    await client.connect()
    
}catch(e){
   console.log(e)
}
 finally{
    await client.close()
}

}

function ListDatabases(client) {
let databases = client.db().admin().listDatabases()
console.log("databases ->")
databases.databases.forEach(element => {
    console.log(`--${element.name}`)
});
}

main()

app.get("/db", function (req, res) {
ListDatabases(client)
return res.json("db")
});

app.listen(8000,() => {
console.log("server running on port 8000")
})
```

how to reference the connected instance in api routes in the above code

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the connection in `finally` block, so as soon as you are connecting, you are also disconnecting it right away.

Remove the `finally` block

```
finally {
    await client.close()
}
```